# Return json with mapping in jpa

Tags: json, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I have 2 table, i want return Employee class with json value. Fetch type of Department is EAGER. But it throw exeption HibernateLazyInitilation. I don't know reason.
Everyone had this problem, please help me.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "DEPARTMENT")
public class Department {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "department_id")
    private int department_id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "department")
    private List<Employee> employees;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "second")
    private List<Employee> employees_2;

}

@Entity
@Table(name="EMPLOYEE")
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "employee_id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "address")
    private String address;

    @Column(name = "phone")
    private String phone;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "department_id")
    private Department department;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "department_id_2")
    private Department second;
```

}

Comment: Maybe you want to show the code for the JPA part & how you create the JSON? Also stack trace would be nice. Yet also: can not see any `@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)` directives?

Comment: i just want show Employee, if i delete the "second" properties, it worked.